# Sitecore Personalize is not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I create a simple demo site for DMS function of Sitecore.
In sitecore content, I created this structure:

Home
|-Personalize
..|-HomeView1
..|-HomeView2

HomeView1, HomeView2 and Home have the same template, which contains only one `Field: Display Text`

Now I create Personalize for home page, set rule for it.
The rule is current month is August and point the Personalize Content to HomeView1.
When I do preview the content doesn't change into text of HomeView1.
Here is my source code:

```csharp
public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected Item currentItem;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    }
}
```

And this what I bound on Home page

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.ascx.cs" Inherits="DMSDemo.sublayouts.HomePage" %>
<div><%= currentItem["Display Text"].ToString() %></div>
```

I wonder why `Sitecore.Context.Item` will not return the correct item (HomeView2) when the personalize rule is applied?

Please give me some advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The context item doesn't change when you personalize, the sublayout's datasource does. So you should set `currentItem` to the datasource.

Here's some common code to get the datasource which I copy/pasted from [Matthew Dresser's blog](http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/sublayout-datasource-for-usercontrol):

```csharp
var sublayout = this.Parent as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout;
if (sublayout != null)
{
    Guid dataSourceId;
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item dataSource;
    if (Guid.TryParse(sublayout.DataSource, out dataSourceId))
    {
        dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(dataSourceId));
    }
    else
    {
        dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(sublayout.DataSource);
    }
}
```

Some other points:

- In general, it's good practice to [avoid the use of the context
  item](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/avoid-the-use-of-sitecore-context-item/)
- There is no requirement for your page item (Home) to be the
  same template has the datasource items.
- I don't think personalization
  works in preview mode, but you can check it in edit mode.

Comment: This issue takes me a ton of time. Thank you very much Davies. It is solved.